# Python Replace fractions in a string

Tags: python, regex, decimal, fractions

I am trying to replace fractions in a string that come in different formats. Some of the formats look like 1/2 , 1 1/2, 1-1/2.

```
Input='This is the first fraction 1/2'
Input_two='This is the second fraction 3-1/8'
Input_three='This is the third fraction 20 1/4'

Output='This is the first fraction 0.5'
Output_two='This is the first fraction 3.12'
Output_three='This is the first fraction 20.25'
```

What I have tried:

```
df['col]=df['col'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('\d\d?\d?.?\d+/\d+','1.5',str(x))
But this only works if you put the value in each time and a thousand different fractions
```

I have also tried `from fractions import Fraction` and `from __future__ import division` but cannot get these to work on strings.

Comment: If the input text is dataframe, then add the sample dataframe to the question, and you can also add `pandas` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) package together with a `re.sub` to do this.

```
import re
from fractions import Fraction

Inputs=[
    'This is the first fraction 1/2',
    'This is the second fraction 3-1/8',
    'This is the third fraction 20 1/4',
    'This is the first fraction 1/2 second fraction 3-1/8 third: 10 3/4'
]

def frac2string(s):
    i, f = s.groups(0)
    f = Fraction(f)
    return str(int(i) + float(f))

[re.sub(r'(?:(\d+)[-\s])?(\d+/\d+)', frac2string, s) for s in Inputs]
```

which gives you:

```
['This is the first fraction 0.5',
 'This is the second fraction 3.125',
 'This is the third fraction 20.25',
 'This is the first fraction 0.5 second fraction 3.125 third: 10.75']
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I did replace the "s" with measure in an applied lambda function and I removed the for s in Inputs since it was an applied Lambda function but it works well! Thank you ```df['col']=df['col'].apply(lambda measure: [re.sub(r'(?:(\d+)[-\s])?(\d+/\d+)', frac2string, measure) )```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using `Series.str.replace` with capturing group, then using `lambda` to convert the fractional values to floating points then do the replacement.

```py
df['col'].str.replace('(\s(?:\d+)?.?\d+\/\d+)', lambda x: ' '+str(eval(x.group(0).replace(' ','+').replace('-',  '+'))), regex=True)

0       This is the first fraction 0.5
1    This is the second fraction 3.125
2     This is the third fraction 20.25
Name: col, dtype: object
```

**PS:** Since, it uses `eval` to convert the string fractional values to the floating values, it will throw `syntaxError` if the fraction part you have mentioned in the question is syntactically wrong, i.e. the actual data is different than  what you have shown in the question.